# Excel - Recursive VLookup

Tags: excel, excel-2007, worksheet-function, vlookup

I recently came to know about Ctrl+Shift+Enter array formulas of Excel and currently still learning them. Coming to my problem,

```
SheetA:
Product        Code
S1             19875
S2             19834
S1             13575
S1             35675
S2             47875   



SheetB:
Code           Indent
19875          40  
19834          15
13575          22
35675          25
47875          20
```

I need to do Sum of all Indents of a given Product name.

Eg: I need S1's Total Indent,

- Vlookup on SheetA, Get the Code 19875
- Perform a vlookup on SheetB, Get the Indent of 40
- Next Vlookup on Sheet A, Get the code 13575
- Use 13575 to Vlookup on SheetB, Get Indent of 22
- Next Vlookup on Sheet A, Get the code 35675
- Use 35675 to Vlookup on SheetB, get indent of 25
- Sum of 40+22+25, Return 87

I can achieve this through VBA, but I'm wondering if this is possible within excel functions using CSE/Array formulas.

Edit:

I don't have values in Sheet2 in the same order of Sheet1.. They are completely random. My SheetB will be something randomly like following:

```
SheetB:
Code           Indent
19834          40  
19875          15
47875          22
13575          25
35675          20
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
{=SUM(NOT(ISNA(MATCH((($A$2:$A$6="S1")*(B2:B6)),Sheet2!$A$2:$A$6,FALSE)))*(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$6))}
```

The first argument of the MATCH resolves to

```
{19875;0;13575;35675;0}
```

The MATCH resolves to

```
{1;#N/A;3;4;#N/A}
```

You'll have to make sure you don't have zeros in SheetB.  The NOT ISNA turns those into TRUEs and FALSEs and resolves to

```
{TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE}
```

And the final SUM looks like this

```
=SUM({TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE}*{40;15;22;25;20})
```

**Update**

I can't figure out a single-array solution when the lists are in a different order.  My attempts with OFFSET and TRANSPOSE either gave the wrong answer or crashed Excel.  If you can stand using a helper column, you could put this formula in third column of your first sheet

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$6,2,FALSE)
```

and then use this array formula to sum them up

```
{=SUM(($A$2:$A$6=A2)*($C$2:$C$6))}
```

Comment: @Kusleika, Thank you for your time. Your solution works fine when I have the codes in Sheet2 in the same order of Sheet1... But that is not the case for my actual data.... Here while typing the example I didn't consider that and just typed some random example. Is there a way to calculate when you are not sure about the order of Sheet2?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did too finally. I didn't want this way, but I inserted extra column into SheetA itself and used SUM(IF('Data-SKUs'!$B:$B=$A9,'Data-SKUs'!$G:$G*'Data-SKUs'!J:J,0). Thank you again for your time D.

Answer (score 0):

If the Code column were identical (same order) on both SheetA and SheetB, a simple SUMIF function would do.  Similarly, if the INDENT data were on SheetA, you could also use a pivot table to calculate the sums quickly.

I'm guessing the design of your workbook won't allow this though.  In which case, I don't have any easy solutions, but I'll give it another look.

Answer (score 0):

On sheetC
If A1 has S1 then in Cell B1 type

```
=SUM((IF((Product=A1),Code1)=TRANSPOSE(Code2))*TRANSPOSE(Amt))
```

Array entered
Where 
Code1 = Dynamic Range for Codes on SheetA starting from Row2
Code2 = Dynamic Range for Codes on SheetB starting from Row2

Answer (score 0):

No `TRANSPOSE` calls needed.

Try the array formula

```
=SUM(SUMIF(SheetB!A2:A6,IF(SheetA!A2:A6="S1",SheetA!B2:B6),SheetB!B2:B6))
```

Assuming no cell in `SheetB!A2:A6` it evaluates to FALSE. If the Code columns were all numeric (probably a questionable assumption), this could be done without an array entry using:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(SheetB!A2:A6,SheetA!B2:B6/(SheetA!A2:A6="S1"),SheetB!B2:B6))
```

Assuming no cell in `SheetB!A2:A6` evaluates to `#DIV/0!`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below:
//Ola.S

Table 1
Col:A   B    C
Product Code Intendent

Col C: =SUMIF($E$4:$E$8;B4;$F$4:$F$8)

Table 2
Col:E F
Code  Intendent

Table 3
Pivottable (Col:A and C)